# What is the point of writing behavioral JUnit test in Spring-Rest?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am new to JUnit mockito, I have this test function written for my Spring rest resource.

```
@Test
public void getAllMessageHappyTest() throws Exception {
    List<Message> messageList = new ArrayList<>();
    messageList.add(new Message(1,"Hello"));
    messageList.add(new Message(5,"Hello world"));
    messageList.add(new Message(3,"Hello World, G!"));

    when(messageService.getAllMessages()).thenReturn(messageList);
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/messages/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();

   String expected = ""; // expected
   JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected,mvcResult.toString(),false);
}
```

In the above scenario, I have the `when(messageService.getAllMessages()).thenReturn(messageList);` returning the `messageList` which is written **by me(or by member of team)** and I am comparing the returned `JSON` with the `String expected` which will also be written **by me(or by the same member of team)**. So both the things are written by the same guy, so what is the point of having such kind of tests.

Comment: the behavior hardcoded in the test is for some service, this tests the controller layer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly the concern is this; because the person who writes the test also hardcodes (in the form of a JSON string) the expectation the test may be redundant or at least may be of limited value. Perhaps the sub text to your question is that since whoever wrote the underlying endpoint will provide the expectation then it must pass and if its success is preordained then it is of little value.

However, regardless of who writes the test and who writes the code-under-test, the example test you showed above has value because:

- It tests more than the retuned JSON, it also tests ...

  - That the REST endpoint mapping is correct i.e. that it exposes an endpoint named `"/messages/"` which accepts JSON
  - The REST layer is using a serialiser which produces some JSON
- Continued running of this test case will ensure that the expected behaviour of this endpoint continues to be met even after you (or some other member of your team) are no longer working on this code or, in other words; it acts as a regression safety net.
- The code-under-test may be changed in future, if so then this test case provides a baseline against which future development can take place.
- The test case provides a form of documentation for your code; people who are unfamiliar with this codebase can review the tests to understand how the code is expected to behave.

In addition, this test case could be extended to include tests for sad paths such as invalid repsonses, unsecured access attempts etc thereby improving test coverage.

**Update 1**: in response ot this comment:

> even if someone makes changes in an actual code and now after making actual code is producing a different kind of JSON(say not as required) even then too test case will pass because when then is hardcoded and expected is also hardcoded. So what is the point?

A test like this clearly makes no sense:

```
String json = "...";

when(foo.getJson()).thenReturn(json);

assertEquals(json, foo.getJson());
```

Bu that is **not** what your test does. Instead your test asserts that the response - in the form of JSON - matches the serialised form of the response returned by your mocked `messageService.getAllMessages()`. So, your test covers the serialisation piece along with the various aspects of the Spring MVC layer such as the endpoint->controller mapping and interceptors and filters (if you have any).

Comment: even if someone makes changes in an actual code and now after making actual code is producing a different kind of JSON(say not as required) even then too test case will pass because `when then is hardcoded` and `expected` is also hardcoded. So what is the point?